# How find a phone number in a string with other content?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that matches a phone number but only if it's the only thing in a string. I need to be able to find a phone number in something like: `"This is your phone number: 111.222.1111. OK?"`.

My current Regex:

```
/(^\(\d{3}\)( |-|\.)?\d{3}( |-|\.)?\d{4}$|^\d{3}( |-|\.)?\d{3}( |-|\.)?\d{4}$|^[0-9]{10,10}$)/g
```

How can I modify this to find phone numbers within a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all of your `^` and `$` symbols in the regex:

```
/(\(\d{3}\)( |-|\.)?\d{3}( |-|\.)?\d{4}|\d{3}( |-|\.)?\d{3}( |-|\.)?\d{4}|[0-9]{10,10})/
```

Here is the **[example](http://regex101.com/r/mX2aN7/1)**

Comment: This works! I was forgetting the `$` and `^` in the middle part of my regex.